# Tikz Package: Drawing Arcs on Circles

Tags: arc

Source: tikz manual on bu.edu
[image]

What does \draw (60:5pt) indicate?

Comment: 5pt from the origin at 60 degrees of direction.

Comment: it is polar coordinate: `60` indicates the polar angle, `5pt` indicate the polar radius. The update PGFmanual is here https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf

Comment: @Jaxx hopefully the answer below will clarify -- moving at 30 degrees or 45 degrees would coincide the smaller arc with the bigger arc -- also note the `shift` syntax which clarifies the movement at an angle -- note also the bigger arc has been drawn with one definition of ` arc(90:390:1cm)` giving the same result -- the author has I believe split into two arcs to help visualize the big and small arc

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (4,3);
\draw [blue]([shift=(60:5pt)]0,0){}--+(30:1cm) arc(30:90:1cm)--cycle;
\draw [red](0,0)--(90:1cm) arc(90:390:1cm)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (4,3);
    \draw [blue]([shift=(30:5pt)]0,0){}--+(30:1cm) arc(30:90:1cm)--cycle;
    \draw [red](0,0)--(90:1cm) arc(90:390:1cm)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[help lines] (0,0) grid (4,3);
    \draw [blue]([shift=(90:5pt)]0,0){}--+(30:1cm) arc(30:90:1cm)--cycle;
    \draw [red](0,0)--(90:1cm) arc(90:390:1cm)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```