# Align two dashed paths

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is it possible to align the dash strokes from two paths which are on top of each other?

In the figure below, the section of the path directly underneath node `c` has a slightly denser dash length due to the two paths on top of each other. Is there a way to avoid this please?

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw] at (-1,-1) (a) {a} ;
  \node[draw] at (0,-1) (b) {b} ;
  \node[draw, anchor=south] at (1,0) (c) {c} ;
  \draw[dashed, ->] (c.south) |- (b.east) ;
  \draw[dashed, <-] (a.south) -- +(270:3mm) -| (c.south); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If I increase the vertical adjustment from node `a` to `+(270:10mm)` this looks better, but of course the adjustment is to large.

Comment: welcome -- please have a look athe answer below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw] at (-1,-1) (a) {a} ;
  \node[draw] at (0,-1) (b) {b} ;
  \node[draw, anchor=south] at (1,0) (c) {c} ;
  \draw[dashed, ->] (c.south) |-coordinate(aux) (b.east) ;
  \draw[dashed, <-] (a.south) -- +(270:3mm) -| (aux); 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: ah, cool. So interpreting your code: a dummy node is added so that each path is only drawn once?

Comment: at the point where the line turns left for the node b -- at that point

Comment: great, thank you

Comment: There's no need for auxiliar node: `\draw[dashed, ->] (c) |- ([yshift=-3mm]a.south)--(a);  \draw[dashed, <-] (b) -- (b-|c);

Comment: @Ignasi It's worth posting that as an alternative answer. The two versions have different dash patterns on the vertical so this is a situation where a small difference in code can produce a visible difference, and then it's very useful to be able to see both versions clearly as separate answers rather than one being buried in comments.  (To be clear, I'm not saying that one is _better_ than the other, just that they are different.)

Comment: @AndrewStacey I've added the answer. Thank you for suggesting it.

Answer (score 3):

Following code, shows an alternative construction with an alternative result. In this case, the line between nodes c and a is drawn first, and the line between this path and node b is drawn later. There is no auxiliary node and no part of this path is drawn twice.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[draw] at (-1,-1) (a) {a} ;
  \node[draw] at (0,-1) (b) {b} ;
  \node[draw, anchor=south] at (1,0) (c) {c} ;
  \draw[dashed, ->] (c) |- ([yshift=-3mm]a.south)--(a); 
  \draw[dashed, <-] (b) -- (b-|c);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ignasi; do I understand correctly that `([yshift=-3mm]a.south)` knida sorta takes the place of a dummy node?

Comment: @user2957945 It's not a node because it has no name and other attributes. It's just a way of defining a coordinate. In this case it's the coordinate which is 3mm below the coordinate corresponding to the anchor `a.south`.

Comment: got it (i think) thanks for the details Ignasi.

Comment: @user2957945 another example of `shift`  have a look --  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/584420/197451